# Which type of url should I use for a mobile website?

Tags: mobile, mobile-web, urls

**Question 1**

Should we give the access to mobile version to all users on desktop. by having a differetn url like http://m.yahoo.com/or it's good to keep mobile version and desktop version access only from mobile and desktop like http://sl.dk. Although advanced user can see by changing UserAgent?

**Question 2**

If we decide to give different url to mobile version and will redirect from main domain to mobile version if user is accessing from mobile then how i should keep url ? though desktop user can also see the mobile version by typing mobile url.

1) Keeping mobile version in sub folder like http://bagcheck.com/mobile

2) With **m.** subdomain like yahoo http://m.yahoo.com/

3) or like http://mobile.twitter.com/

4) or a totally different url http://website.mobi

Comment: All of the above! Really how hard is it to create one mobile version of the site and redirect a couple of URL's that way. Make the shortest one to type the one thats shown everywhere.

Comment: As mobile user I like 'm.site.com' url most of all, because it does not take up much space in url bar. Also, 301 redirect from 'mobile.site.com' and 'site.com/mobile' to 'm.site.com' would be great.

Comment: @Dmitry - and would u like to acess m.site.com from desktop if you find mobile version better than desktop for you?

Comment: Though site.mobi can be shorther than m.site.com and site.mobi has only single period.

Comment: @Jitendra It's hard to imagine for me when mobile version is better for desktop. But I like to know that mobile version is avaliable.

Comment: Example: I like to use Mobile version of Google Reader even on desktop because it has less cultter http://www.google.com/reader/i/

Answer (score 2):

Question 1 Answer: 
The goal here is to provide the most suitable information to each purpose.

The http://m.subdomain.com/ url typically means that there is a unique website - typically a subset of the full website - that was purpose-built for mobile devices.  You'll see it used quite a bit nowadays as it is the 'easiest' way to implement a mobile strategy across a website.

When an Advanced user switches their User Agent to a mobile device, they know what to expect.  Switching User Agents isn't something a regular visitor will partake in.

Question 2 Answer: 
The answer to this question may fall outside the scope of this board (also, I don't see a difference between your examples 2) and 3) - they're both sub domains.).

The ideal solution here is to have a Responsive Web Design (more info: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) as this means 1 source of content, 1 source of templates and a device agnostic design that suits desktop, tablet and mobile.

Comment: difference between 2 and 3 is less character to type. Responsive webdesign is not for all cases http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1390

Answer (score 1):

Please see:

http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/02/23/a-better-way-to-add-mobile-pages-to-a-rails-site/

> ## Adding a Custom Domain Sucks
>
> Don’t you hate it when you see a link to an article on Twitter and
>   click it on your desktop, only to be taken to http://m.whatever.com/
>   because someone shared this link from their mobile device? Now you’re
>   reading a mobile version of this article full screen on your desktop
>   and it looks ridiculous. Or you hit a full version URL from your
>   mobile device and have to suffer yet another redirect. As a user, I
>   would prefer to see one page that looks mobile-friendly on a mobile
>   device, and looks like a full version on a desktop. As a developer,
>   redirecting seems like a cop-out. It also feels like it violates a
>   good RESTful design. There should be one URL for this resource and its
>   view should be tailored to the device on which I am viewing it.

Comment: This answer seems particular to Ruby. It also doesn't really address the question directly (Though, admittedly, the question is now rather dated).